# Json server is already install in Ubuntu but i gets error that json-server : command not found

Tags: angular, typescript, json-server

I installed `json-server` using command `npm install json-server`, In my package.json, I can see `json-server` is installed but when I tried to start it, it gets error that:

> `json-server` : command not found

I also tried `sudo npm install json-server` and `sudo npm install -g json-server` but nothing works.

Comment: `sudo npm install -g json-server` should work. Does `npm list -g --depth=0` list `json-server`?

Comment: "sudo npm install -g json-server" command runs with error

Comment: What is the error when you run it? AFAIK, `json-server` should be installed in the global mode(`-g`). You should also have it added to the `PATH` environment variable in order to run it(as far as Windows is concerned).

Comment: "Refusing to delete /usr/local/bin/json-server: ../lib/node_modules/json-server/bin/index.js symlink target is not controlled by npm /usr/local"

Comment: how to set path in linux

Answer (score 1):

login as root and install it using

```
sudo su
npm install -g json-server
exit
```

Comment: If one can sudo, why not just `sudo npm install...` ?

Comment: @Tiw, because you will not have the same set of environment variables using sudo su. and particularly the PATH environment variable. the later one will reflect root user's one

Comment: Thank you!! This worked for me. I had tried a lot of solutions but was getting the same error.